# Does setting read ahead parameter affect open files/ running processes?

Tags: linux-kernel, storage, block-device

Does setting the read ahead parameter using the `blockdev` command affects open files and running process?

Example: The default value for read ahead is 256.

Suppose I run the following:

```
sudo blockdev --setra 8 /dev/sdX
```

Will this instantly enter in effect and will affect all running processes which have files open in a partition mounted from `/dev/sdxn`?

If not, what is the minimal for this to enter in effect? Is restarting the processes so that they can open the files again enough or do I need to remount the partition?